# cannot access only magento admin dashboard after login

Tags: php, magento, url, admin, dashboard

[image]

in the above image you can see that i cannot access my admin dashboard after login the URL is like 
*http://www.synapse.com.pk/magento/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/4cbad50e2887ea912e3932a96742ca5b/*

can anyone tell what is the actual problem i am facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed index.php from provided url and i can see admin panel login check below :

http://www.synapse.com.pk/magento/admin/dashboard/index/key/4cbad50e2887ea912e3932a96742ca5b/